# 2 videos out of sync

Tags: framerate, sync

I recorded myself using my camera (canon ixus 117hs, 23.98fps) and also recorded my LG G3 using AZrecorder (records the screen at 55.58fps). I tried to sync both videos (using premiere pro cc) and at some point they go out of sync, maybe because of the difference in the fps? and if so, what can I do with it? Thank you.

Comment: If they drift gradually out of sync after you sync the beginning, probably your camera and computer have a different idea of how long a second is.  You need to stretch one or the other of the videos.  (stretching the one without audio is going to be simpler.)  Why 55.58fps, though?  Your monitor refresh isn't really that far off 60Hz, is it?  Mine are both about 59.9Hz.

Comment: I had this problem recently with premiere and spent an entire day trying to sync my videos. Were your videos variable frame rate? Adobe Premiere doesn't support variable frame rate videos. When you try to use them, they eventually go out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

55.58 is not a standard frame rate so it's the one that should be changed. Using the 23.98 video as a reference, pick a point late into the video where you can determine how many frames (at 23.98 fps) it's out of sync with the 56 fps video. Compute the ratio of the length in frames up to that point, to the number of frames out of sync. Then time stretch the entire 56 fps video --  either shorter of longer as needed -- using that ratio.

Comment: I didn't understand what to do, by the way, I tried to change the speed of the video and it fit well but after a while it goes out of sync again

Comment: Do you mean that the total lengths match, but it goes in and out of sync, or what exactly? If the 56 fps isn't a constant rate, then you might end up applying a different speed change for each section that's out of sync.

Comment: I don't know because the video from the smartphone is really long and the video from the camera is divided to 10 minute parts